# urllib3 + BS4 Connection broken: IncompleteRead(61064 bytes read)

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, urllib

Такая проблема, не гуглится ничего на этот счет.
Ошибка возникает эпизодически. В первый раз после нее упал сайт, к которому я подключался, ну я подумал что из-за этого. Но сейчас опять такая же фигня. А сайт до сих пор работает и браузером открывается.

Код:

```
import urllib3
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://'
user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'}
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', 
                           ca_certs=certifi.where(),
                           headers=user_agent)  # проверка сертификатов SSL
response = http.request('GET', url, preload_content=False)

# до сюда код работает без ошибок

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

# после супа вылетает с ошибкой Connection broken: IncompleteRead(61064 bytes read)
```

Comment: И опять падает сайт, через 5 часов после возникновения у меня ошибки чтения. Хммм, странно это все. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исключение грамотно тут сформировать, чтобы мой код продолжал выполнятся.